# Ansible pattern matching doesn't work as expected

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am unable to find why this simple pattern doesn't seem to match anything. I have two Ansible hosts as targets. This is my inventory file:

```
[web_Xubuntu]
192.168.160.128

[database_Fedora]
192.168.160.132
```

And this is what my YAML playbook looks like:

```
  # Hosts: where our play will run and options it will run with
  hosts: *Fedora
  become: True
    #gather_facts: False

  # Vars: variables that will apply to the play, on all target systems
  vars:
    motd: "Welcome to Fedora Linux - Ansible Rocks\n"

  # Tasks: the list of tasks that will be executed within the playbook
  tasks:
    - name: Configure a MOTD (message of the day)
      copy:
        content: "{{ motd }}"
        dest: /etc/motd
      notify: MOTD changed

  # Handlers: the list of handlers that are executed as a notify key from a task
  handlers:
    - name: MOTD changed
      debug:
        msg: The MOTD was changed
```

On processing this playbook, Ansible reports the following error:

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found undefined alias

The offending line appears to be:

  # Hosts: where our play will run and options it will run with
  hosts: *Fedora
         ^ here
```

What is the right way to use a wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the asterisk `*`( wildcard) with FQDN or IP only. For example,

```
192.0.*
*.example.com
*.com
```

See [Patterns: targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-targeting-hosts-and-groups).

Use the inventory plugin *constructed* if you want to run all `*Fedora` groups. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t inventory constructed
```

For example, given the tree

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── 01-hosts
│   └── 02-constructed.yml
└── pb.yml

1 directory, 4 files
```

the inventory

```ini
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts 
[web_Xubuntu]
192.168.160.128

[database_Fedora]
192.168.160.132

[web_Fedora]
192.168.160.133
```

the *contructed* plugin

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml 
plugin: constructed
groups:
  Fedora: group_names|select('regex', '^.*Fedora$')
```

Test the inventory

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory  -i inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    Fedora:
      hosts:
        192.168.160.132: {}
        192.168.160.133: {}
    database_Fedora:
      hosts:
        192.168.160.132: {}
    ungrouped: {}
    web_Fedora:
      hosts:
        192.168.160.133: {}
    web_Xubuntu:
      hosts:
        192.168.160.128: {}
```

Then, test the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: Fedora
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory pb.yml 

PLAY [Fedora] *********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.160.132] => 
  inventory_hostname: 192.168.160.132
ok: [192.168.160.133] => 
  inventory_hostname: 192.168.160.133

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
192.168.160.132: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
192.168.160.133: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```